# Probability that either one, but not both is chosen

Tags: combinatorics

A basketball team of 5 is to be selected from 12 players. Find the probability that either one, but not both of the captain or vice-captain are selected.

So I thought the answer is:
 $$2\frac{{10}\choose{4}}{12\choose{5}}$$

Because if the captain is to be in the team, then you select the other 4 from the remaining 10, not 11, because there can't be both captain and vice-captain in the team at the same time. The same goes if the vice-captain is to be included, hence I multiply by two.

According to the textbook, however, the answer is $\frac{5}{6}$. Why?

Comment: Textbooks can be wrong you know

Comment: I know, but is it wrong in this case? ;)

Comment: Your answer is correct.  (To check it, you could add the probability that both players are selected and the probability that neither of them is selected, and then subtract from 1.)

Comment: Note:  the probability that the captain, say, is chosen is clearly $\frac 5{12}$.  The text's answer is exactly twice that, which is clearly too high.

Comment: @lulu What is the easiest way to see that this probability is $\frac{5}{12}$?

Comment: @user84413  Each team member draws (without replacement) from an urn containing $5$ red marbles and $7$ blue ones.  Those who choose the red ones are selected.

Comment: @lulu Thanks - that's simpler than anything I came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, it is essentially $\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{12}{5}} = \frac{35}{66}$, where you choose one of the captain/vice-captain group and 4 from the others.

To verify this we can compute the other probabilities as well:

both are chosen with probability $\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{10}{3}}{\binom{12}{5}} = \frac{5}{33} = \frac{10}{66}$, whereas none are chosen with probability 
$\frac{\binom{2}{0}\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{12}{5}} = \frac{7}{22} = \frac{21}{66}$ and all these nicely sum up to 1.